# Extra Space at bottom of page in some browsers

Tags: css, html

I am having problems having "extra space" at bottom of page. in Opera, and firefox. and on IE, sometiems it happens sometimes it doesn't on chrome works fine all the time. I am new to css and html5, and on top of that. haven't done any web design in a lot of time. used to just use tables and old html. the website i'm having problem with is

 http://jconstruction.us.cloudlogin.co/index2.php 
I tried everything and now i gave up. it is a modified template the templates works well in all browsers so my guess is is some of my modification. the template where i having problem is from here 
 http://www.jonathansconstruction.com 

if anyone can help will be glad. 
Thanks in advance I am really needing this spent lot of time with no success

Edit

Thansks a lot for all the HeLP ..... I did manage to fix the problem on most browsers, However, still having a hard time on IE, if anyone can help will be greatly appreciated (already about to pull my hair out ) lol.. I even tried validating. and although some errors, i tried taking the errors aout and still, same result.

Comment: You have some [HTML validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjconstruction.us.cloudlogin.co%2Findex2.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) including duplicate ID's.  With invalid HTML, you are almost certainly going to have cross-browser rendering issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, set this property

```
      .ui-datepicker
         {
          position:absolute;
         }
```

Comment: Thank you the ui.datepicker{position:absolute;} Definitely Solve problems for all browsers, howver, in IE, i'm still having some trouble witht he footer, (i am using IE 7) i know is old but i also want it to be compatible with older browsers. on top of that the  facebook "like" button, when i click on it, the "box" that appears to add comment in IE appears behind the content hence I don't see it. and also, the figcaption image can't make it appear same way as it does on other browsers any help appreciated and thanks again

Comment: I cant access any social network buttons , i am in my office social sites are blocked here , anyway i found the css issue , .contain_social {float:right;margin:0 auto;} this is wrong if you want to work margin auto property you have to remove float property . Thanks

Comment: I did remove the margin auto did not make any difference. If you get a chance let me know about the social buttons. Also, what can it be the problem in IE7? still have extra space at buttom of page Thanks

Comment: Here is the screen Shot, this is the problem with the extra space at bottom of page (only in IE) all others works fine with the fix you sent me. THanks! .. http://i46.tinypic.com/2mdmczk.jpg  and on the social button, this is how it looks on ie (you can see the arrow pointing at the like button http://i45.tinypic.com/2h4zwn4.jpg but this is how it should look, which is how it looks on all other browsers : http://i45.tinypic.com/6hnuo8.jpg

Comment: Did not solve yet 'bottom space'? ,  i understood the social media alignment problem, but i cant check, i think problem is position "relative" property, check these divs relative property  #social_media, .contain_social

Comment: Thanks, will do that, and let you know how it goes. Will do it tomorrow however, because need to wake up early tomorrow.. and is late here...  the bottom space was solved in all browsers except IE 7 .. and i dont know what the problem is yet

Comment: I played arround with the property of position:relative and well... i found a work-around because if i took it out something diff in the design will happen but finally works. now all is left is the problem with extra space at bottom of page on IE only

Comment: Found something interesting in the footer on IE, when I add position:absolute; to it, the space gets smaller, yet, does not dissapear

Comment: Sure, Screenshot is http://i49.tinypic.com/6iw3gp.jpg and Link is http://jconstruction.us.cloudlogin.co

Comment: .ui-datepicker { top:0;} try postion for ie

Comment: do i put a conditioning statement or just add it somewhere?

Comment: well, it worked, but the calendar now is all the way at the top ?? on all browsers

Comment: Im sorry- go  http://jconstruction.us.cloudlogin.co/css/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css , line No- 43 , remove margin. ok?

Comment: ".ui-datepicker { top:0;} try postion for ie " this was my wrong answer i am sorry,  
Im sorry- go jconstruction.us.cloudlogin.co/css/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css , line No- 43 , remove margin. ok?

Comment: yeah is perfect now, i totally forgot i had that code there... THanks a lot for the help  !

Comment: btw, i guess is not very important, i'm' trying to make my html5 as valid as possible. however i did use some ul elements in the <h4> ust to line up as columns subheaders i u could probably see, if there is a way to do it differently to line up let me know,

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjconstruction.us.cloudlogin.co%2F

Comment: yeah i validatd there, it showed me the 3 errores saying ul not allowed as child element of h4, as u can see i used it for some headings to make it two columns.. because the other way i know is div positioning or i guess h4 positioning but i do not know if there is another way to do it

Comment: i found more error, <address>
          <u>CONTACT INFO </u><br>34 Albany ave <br>
Nutley, NJ 07110 <br>
Office: (973) 816 - 5405 <br>
Cellular: (862) 208 - 0777 <br></address> please set <ul><li></li></ul> do must this order, Dear  I am in office little busy,  "shibinragh" this is my skype ok?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you might have used `top:-***px;` in the CSS for any `<div>`.  Try using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I usually create two parts to the page:

```
<body>
    <div id="main-part"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Then style it:

```
#main-part { height: 100%; padding-bottom: 110px; }
#footer { height: 100px; margin-top: -100px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using fixed headers and footers in a `div` with the 100% height, so that the space will not mess up in any browsers.  If you can try over `position:relative` also and try setting `margin-top` values for the space.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I found the solution by making change in the CSS:

```
.Zebra_DatePicker.dp_hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0
}
```

Instead of  **`visibility: hidden;`** use **`display:none;`** and it will work perfectly.